# Jquery UI Tabs: Next and Previous enable/disable based on select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I am currently working with Jquery UI tabs that I have only operating with next/previous buttons(this will force the user to go through the tabs in order). In my first tab I have a set of dynamic select boxes and I am trying to get the user to choose a category and its subcategory from that corresponds before given the possibility to enable the NEXT button. But the next button is not being disabled at all.

How can I get the user to choose from all the corresponding select boxes and then enabling the NEXT button? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/test1.php)

I added `$('.update').change(function()` to the JS for NEXT/PREVIOUS to detect the  selected item in the last select box and give the go for the NEXT Button

**JS for NEXT/Previous**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
        disabled: [0, 1]
    });

    $(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(i) {
        var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;

        if (i != totalSize) {
            next = i + 2;
            $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Next Page &#187;</a>");
        }

        if (i != 0) {
            prev = i;
            $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'>&#171; Prev Page</a>");
        }
    });

    $('.update').change(function() {
        $('#tabs').tabs(
            'option',
            'disabled',
            (
                $(this).hasClass('last') &&
                parseInt($(this).val(), 10) > 0 ?
                [] :
                [1]
            )
        );
    });

    $('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() {
        var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
        $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex)
            .tabs('select', tabIndex)
            .tabs("option","disabled", [0, 1]);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

**upadateSelectBox.js**

```
// following line is added to detect last select box picked
$('.update').removeClass('last');
if (!data.error) {
    obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled hidden');
} else {
    // following line is changed
    obj.addClass('last').nextAll('.update').attr({'disabled': true, 'hidden':true}).html('<option value="">----</option>');
}
```

**HTML of select boxes**

```
<select name="gender" id="gender" class="update" size="7"> 
  <option value="">Select one</option> 
    <?php if (!empty($list)) { ?> 
        <?php foreach($list as $row) { ?> 
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> 
                <?php echo $row['category_name']; ?> 
   </option> 
    <?php } ?> 
    <?php } ?> 
</select> 

<select name="category" id="category" class="update" disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden" size="7"> 
   <option value="">----</option> 
</select> 

<select name="colour" id="colour" class="update" disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden" size="7"> 
   <option value="">----</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome back. Sorry, I don't understand your changes. What do you want to achieve? Why do you disable the first tab, that makes no sense. Why do you first enable one tab and disable all immediately? What has disturbed you in the last version?

Comment: @scessor Hey! thankyou, The reason is that i want to have the TAB menu disabled at all times. I only want the user to go through the tabs with the next/previous button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is untested. Only change the tab on next/previous click, if you are not on the first tab *(1)* or the *really last* tab exist and an option (except the neutral) is choosen *(2)*.

```
$('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() {
    var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
    if (
        /*(1)*/ $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected') > 0 ||
        /*(2)*/ ($('.update.last').length > 0 && parseInt($('.update.last').val(), 10) > 0)
    ) {
        $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex)
            .tabs('select', tabIndex)
            .tabs("option","disabled", [0, 1]);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Good luck and see you tomorrow :-)

Comment: hey my friend, I am working with this method but now I have included input fields. If you like to earn more points here is the [QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678745/jquery-ui-tabs-advancing-tabs-with-next-previous-buttons-depending-on-input-fie#11678908)