# Jquery UI tabs- Advancing tabs with Next/Previous buttons depending on input fields values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I am using Jquery UI Tabs that are operated only with a previous and next button. In my first tab I have select boxes and in order to advance you have to choose an option from the select box. My concern is in Tab#2 I have three input fields which I would like the user to fill before going any further.

How can I disable the Next button so the user is forced to fill the input fields before advancing to the next tab? [EXAMPLE](http://www.google.com)

**JS- NEXT/PREVIOUS**

```
<script>
        $(function() {

                var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
                    disabled: [0, 1]
                });

                $(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(i) {

                    var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;

                    if (i != totalSize) {
                        next = i + 2;
                        $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Next Page &#187;</a>");
                    }

                    if (i != 0) {
                        prev = i;
                        $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'>&#171; Prev Page</a>");
                    }

                });


                $('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() {
                    var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
                    if (
                        /*(1)*/ $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected') > 0 ||
                        /*(2)*/ ($('.update.last').length > 0 && parseInt($('.update.last').val(), 10) > 0)
                    ) {
                        $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex)
                            .tabs('select', tabIndex)
                            .tabs("option","disabled", [0, 1]);
                    }
                    return false;
                });

        });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tab-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
  <label for="title"> Title: *</label>
    <input type="text"  id="title" name="title" class="" size="33" autocomplete="off" value="<? $title ?>"/><br>
    <label for="price"> Price: *</label>             
      <input type="text" name="price" class="" size="8" maxlength="9" id="price" autocomplete="off" value="<? $price ?>" /><br>
           <label for="description"> Description: *</label> 
         <textarea id="description" name="description" class=""><? $description ?></textarea><br />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only change the tab on *next* or *prev* button, if

- (A) the *prev* button has been clicked or
- (B) current tab is the 1st one, a *really last* select exists and there an option is choosen or
- (C) current tab is the 2nd one and all ([trimmed](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)) text-values are not empty.

Here is the next untested extension:

```
$('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() {
    var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
    if (
        $(this).hasClass('prev-tab') ||                          /*(A)*/
        (
            $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected') == 0 &&        /*(B)*/
            $('.update.last').length > 0 && 
            parseInt($('.update.last').val(), 10) > 0
        ) ||
        (
            $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected') == 1 &&        /*(C)*/ 
            $.trim($('#title').val()).length > 0 && 
            $.trim($('#price').val()).length > 0 &&
            $.trim($('#description').val()).length > 0
        )
    ) {
        $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex)
            .tabs('select', tabIndex)
            .tabs("option","disabled", [0, 1]);
    }
    return false;
});
```

=== UPDATE ===

Added a tab specific alert:

```
$('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() {
    var prev = $(this).hasClass('prev-tab');
    var currentTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
    if (
        prev ||                                                  /*(A)*/
        (
            currentTab == 0 &&                                   /*(B)*/
            $('.update.last').length > 0 &&
            parseInt($('.update.last').val(), 10) > 0
        ) ||
        (
            currentTab == 1 &&                                   /*(C)*/
            $.trim($('#title').val()).length > 0 &&
            $.trim($('#price').val()).length > 0 &&
            $.trim($('#description').val()).length > 0
        )
    ) {
        var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
        $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex)
            .tabs('select', tabIndex)
            .tabs("option","disabled", [0, 1]);
    } else if (!prev) {
        switch (currentTab) {
            case 0:
                alert('Please choose an option.');
                break;
            case 1:
            case 2:
                alert('Please fill out all form inputs.');
                break;
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Tried it and it worked perfect. wow without a doubt you are a jquery guru.

Comment: I am going to try to implement a way to see if the user does not complete an input field and click button, then show an alert "Please complete the required fields"

Comment: would it be possible to add something like this inside the parentheses for an alert if user still clicks the next button without filling out the required  fields:       `if ($i.length != $i.filter('[value!=""]').length) {
         alert("Please fill out all form inputs.");
         return false;
       }`

Comment: You should add an ajax loader (just before the `jQuery.getJSON` in the _updateSelectBox.js_) so that nothing can be clicked while loading on the first tab and remove it after the success handling (in the same file). I'm away for this weekend, seeyou.

Comment: thank you my friend. I would take that into consideration. But before you go I have added an extra tab with more input fields and have set it just like the others to validate but no alert box is coming up when clicking the next button. If you like check my example site. Thankyou once again

Comment: For each tab you have to add a `case` in the `switch` (also for the 3rd tab). I've updated my answer. Alternative you can add a `default`. Seeyou.

Comment: that makes perfect sense when using cases in the switch, thank you, Enjoy and have a great weekend see you!

Comment: My friend, remember your suggestion about ajax loader. If you want more points: [QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694432/ajax-loader-and-chained-select-boxes)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a validate function that looks at the selected tab and then the items that need to be filled out for next to be enabled. This function can then be bound on change to each of the items that need to be filled out.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the click event handler:

```
$('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() {
  var $t = $(this), tabIndex = $t.attr("rel");
  if ($t.hasClass("prev-tab")) {
    if ($("input").filter('[value=""]').length) {
      alert("Please fill out all form inputs.");
      return false;
    }
  }
...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 Thank you, One thing that I am having issue(I am not sure if I modified the click event handler properly) but the user can still advanced to the next tab without having to type anything into the input field. Updated [LINK](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/test1.php)

Comment: I just made an edit... maybe that'll fix it? I was, perhaps, being a bit to brief. If you return false, that should prevent the link from working.

Comment: I changed it to your edited answer but it is not working properly. You can check with Example site to see the results.

Comment: I've edited the code once again -- it is now shorter and simpler. Basically, if any inputs have an empty value (the user did not fill in the field), the filter method will return those elements. The (inner) if conditional will be true (and execute the alert statement), if any inputs have a blank value.