# Ajax Loader and chained select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am working with dynamic select boxes and I am using JS/Jquery to update the values of each select box. Since I am pulling the values from MySQL table, sometimes it takes a little longer to load the select boxes with its values. One Solution i search is the use of an ajax loader.

How can I place an ajax loader (just before the jQuery.getJSON in the updateSelectBox.js) so that nothing can be clicked while loading on the first tab and remove it after the success handling (in the same file)? or any better solutions? Here is an [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/test1.php)

**updateSelectBox.js**

```
var formObject = {
    run : function(obj) {

            obj.nextAll('.update').attr({'disabled': true, 'hidden':true}).html('<option value="">----</option>');
            var id = obj.attr('id');
            var v = obj.val();
            jQuery.getJSON('mod/postfile.php', { id : id, value : v }, function(data) {
            $('.update').removeClass('last');
                if (!data.error) {
                    obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled hidden');
                } else {
                 obj.addClass('last').nextAll('.update').attr({'disabled': true, 'hidden':true}).html('<option value="">----</option>');
                }
            });
        }   
}; 

$(function(){

    $('.update').live('change', function() {
        var str = "";
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
              });
          $("#postSelected").text(str);

        formObject.run($(this));
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="gender" id="gender" class="update" size="7"> 
  <option value="">Select one</option> 
    <?php if (!empty($list)) { ?> 
    <?php foreach($list as $row) { ?> 
       <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> 
        <?php echo $row['category_name']; ?> 
       </option> 
    <?php } ?> 
    <?php } ?> 
</select> 

<select name="category" id="category" class="update" disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden" size="7"> 
  <option value="">----</option> 
</select> 

<select name="colour" id="colour" class="update" disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden" size="7"> 
  <option value="">----</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should create an ajax loader image (e.g. [here](http://ajaxload.info/)) and save it on your server. Just before the *getJSON* the ajaxloader overlay should be shown (customize the image source!):

```
$('#tabs').append('<div class="overlay"><div class="overlay_image"><img src="ajaxloader.gif" alt="ajaxloader"></div></div>');
$('#tabs .overlay').css("line-height", $('#tabs').height()+'px');
```

And remove it at the end of the success handler:

```
$('#tabs .overlay').remove();
```

Your *formObject* should be now:

```
var formObject = {
    run : function(obj) {
        obj.nextAll('.update').attr({'disabled': true, 'hidden':true}).html('<option value="">----</option>');
        var id = obj.attr('id');
        var v = obj.val();
        $('#tabs').append('<div class="overlay"><div class="overlay_image"><img src="ajaxloader.gif" alt="ajaxloader"></div></div>');
        $('#tabs .overlay').css("line-height", $('#tabs').height()+'px');
        jQuery.getJSON('mod/postfile.php', { id : id, value : v }, function(data) {
        $('.update').removeClass('last');
            if (!data.error) {
                obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled hidden');
            } else {
             obj.addClass('last').nextAll('.update').attr({'disabled': true, 'hidden':true}).html('<option value="">----</option>');
            }
            $('#tabs .overlay').remove();
        });
    }   
};
```

Following additional stylesheets are necessary to see the overlay:

```
#tabs {
    position: relative;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2000;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.overlay > div {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.overlay > img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/UZ3x4/).

Comment: Hey my friend! thank you. I tried your code and seems to be working but its causing some css issues to the tab. Check the [LINK](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/test1.php)

Comment: I am currenlty working with a new question. If you like to get more points here it is: [QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726827/wmd-editor-echoing-value-of-wmd-preview-div-and-inquiries-about-storing-that-val)

Answer (score 0):

One alternative approach for you to consider: your MySQL queries should not take very long at all. These are really simple lookups; if they take long, there are probably missing indexes. Before adding the pre-loading logic, I would see how long the queries take on the back-end, and try to optimize those queries.