# WMD Editor echoing value of wmd-preview div and inquiries about storing that value into a database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently trying to add the WMD editor to my site. I have everything working so far but now I am running into wall: How to store the typed information into my database? I have created a JS/Ajax function that will assign the value of textarea to `$wmdVal` but instead i actually value of the `wmd-preview` since it contains the html formatted code. How can I get the value of the div `wmd-preview` and assigned it php variable? or what is the best way to store it in a database? Here is my [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/test1.php)

**JS/AJAX echoing value in realtime**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer = null; 
    var dataString;   
    function submitForm(){
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
         url: "test1.php",
         data: dataString,
             success: function(result){
            $('#wmd_result').html( $('#resultval', result).html()); 
              }
       });
        return false;
      }

 $('#wmd-input').on('keyup', function() {
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 1000);
var wmdVal = $("#wmd-input").val();
dataString = 'wmdVal='+ wmdVal;
});
}); 
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['wmdVal'])){
    $wmdVal = $_POST['wmdVal']; 
    echo ('<div id="wmd_result"><span id="resultval"><h2>PHP Echo result:</h2>'.$wmdVal.'</span></div>');
        }
?>
```

**HTML WMD Editor**

```
<div id="wmd-editor" class="wmd-panel">
      <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
      <textarea id="wmd-input"><? $wmdVal ?></textarea>
</div>
<div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel"></div>
<div id="wmd-output" class="wmd-panel"></div>   
<div id="wmd_result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a hidden field in your form and on submit, get the value of `wmd-preview` and assign it into the hidden field and let the form submit. then access your hidden field in `$_POST` array as a normal input field and save it.

you can access the `wmd-preview` as

```
 $("#myhidden").val($("#wmd-preview").html());
```

Comment: +1 @RabNawaz thank you, can you post the complete answer with my example involved? I added a hidden input field but I am not sure how to do the other requirements to show the value of `wmd-preview`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly I think you only have to replace

```
var wmdVal = $("#wmd-input").val();
```

with

```
var wmdVal = $("#wmd-preview").html();
```

in your code above.

Comment: hey my friend nice try. Here is another question for your interest [QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754774/submit-input-field-value-with-jquery-ui-next-button-and-php-echo-the-result)