# Submit input field value with jquery UI next button and php echo the result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currenlty working with jquery ui tabs(which works only with next/previous buttons) and a textarea. I have developed an ajax/js function that will auto submit the value stored in the text area and php echo the result in tab#2. But I am currently want to change the method from auto submitting the form to submit when the user clicks the Next button to adavance to the next. How can I submit the value inside a text field when clicking the next button in a jquery ui tabs? Here is my [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/test1.php) with autosubmit

**PREVIOUS/NEXT**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
    disabled: [0, 1] });
    $(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(i) {
             var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;
                         if (i != totalSize) {
        next = i + 2;
            $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Next Page &#187;</a>");
                    }

     if (i != 0) {
    prev = i;
    $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'>&#171; Prev Page</a>");
    }
});

 $('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() {
    var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
    $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex)
    .tabs('select', tabIndex)
    .tabs("option","disabled", [0, 1]);
    return false;
});

});
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<?
  if (isset($_POST['wmdVal'])){
    $wmdVal = $_POST['wmdVal']; 
        echo ('<div id="wmd_result"><span id="resultval"><h2>PHP Echo result:</h2>'.$wmdVal.'</span></div>');
}
?>

<textarea id="wmd-input" name="wmd-input"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" id="myhidden" name="myhidden" value="<? $wmdVal ?>">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember on which tab you are (`currentTab`). If a tab is selected, check if the first tab is leaving; if yes send the ajax request with the current *preview html*; no success handler is needed, we don't need any client changes. If the next tab is shown, reset the `currentTab` index. On server side (php) you can e.g. save the data to the database but doesn't need any result.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/postingtabs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="css/wmd.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/wmd.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/showdown.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var currentTab = 0;

        $(function() {
            var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
                disabled: [0, 1]
                , select: function() {
                    if (currentTab == 0) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "test1.php",
                            data: { "wmdVal": $("#wmd-preview").html() }
                        });
                    }
                }
                , show: function(event, ui) {
                    currentTab = ui.index;
                }
            });

            $(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(i) {
                var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;
                if (i != totalSize) {
                    next = i + 2;
                    $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Next Page &#187;</a>");
                }
                if (i != 0) {
                    prev = i;
                    $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'>&#171; Prev Page</a>");
                }
            });

            $('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() {
                var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
                $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex)
                    .tabs('select', tabIndex)
                    .tabs("option","disabled", [0, 1]);
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tab-1">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-2">2</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="tab-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
                <div id="wmd-editor" class="wmd-panel">
                    <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
                    <textarea id="wmd-input" name="wmd-input"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="tab-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

=== UPDATE ===

If you really want to see a result temporarily for testing, add the success handler again to the ajax parameters:

```
success: function(result) {
    $('#wmd_result').html( $('#resultval', result).html()); 
}
```

And append the result `div` again to the end of first tab:

```
<div id="wmd_result"></div>
```

Comment: This is perfect! thank you again my friend. Tried and tested and works flawlessly.

Comment: Hey my friend just in case you didnt see it here is my next question: [CLICK HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791140/ajax-submit-various-input-values-with-jquery-ui-next-button-click)