# Submit input field value with button click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working with an ajax form that it is suppose to submit with a button click. I have seen similar projects but I am running into dead ends. The problem i am having is that the input field values are not getting echo in tab 2. I set a parameter `var currentTab` to indicate and compare when a click has been made to the next tab.

- How can I display the value of the input fields after a click has been made?
- (Additional)  Also how can adapt the code if in the future I have multiple tabs with input fields and the last tab will be where the values get php echo out?

Thank you

**AJAX/JS Function**

```
<script>  
var currentTab = 0;
        $(function() {
            var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
                disabled: [0, 1]
                , select: function() {
                    if (currentTab == 0) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "tabs.php",
                            data: { "textarea": $("#textarea_input").html(),
                "title": $("#title_input").html()   
                  },
            success: function(result) {
              $("#tab-2").html(result);
            }

                    });

        }
                }
                , show: function(event, ui) {
                    currentTab = ui.index;
                }
            });

$(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(i) {
  var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;
       if (i != totalSize) {
              next = i + 2;
               $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Next Page &#187;</a>");
                }
        if (i != 0) {
              prev = i;
              $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'>&#171; Prev Page</a>");
              }
});

$('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() {
    var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
    $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex)
    .tabs('select', tabIndex)
    .tabs("option","disabled", [0, 1]);
    return false;
            });
});
 </script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['title'])){
    $title = $_POST['title']; 
    echo ('<div id="title_result"><span class="resultval"><h2>Title Echo result:</h2>'.$title.'</span></div>');
            }

if (isset($_POST['textarea'])){
    $textarea = $_POST['textarea']; 
    echo ('<div id="textarea_result"><span class="resultval"><h2>Textarea Echo result:</h2>'.$textarea.'</span></div>');
            }

?>
```

**HTML** Tab2 is where the results should be php echo out

```
<div id="tab-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
     <input type="text" id="title_input" name="title_input" size="60" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$title?>"/><br>
     <label for="textarea_input">Textarea</label>
     <textarea id="textarea_input" name="textarea_input"><?=$textarea?></textarea> 
</div>

<div id="tab-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide"> 
    <div id="title_result" style="padding:20px;"></div>
    <div id="textarea_result" style="padding:20px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: similar post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754774/submit-input-field-value-with-jquery-ui-next-button-and-php-echo-the-result

Comment: We are talking about Ajax. Clicking "submit" won't reload the page.

Comment: you should use `$("#textarea-input").val()` instead of `$("#textarea-input").html()` - your input is not sent to the server at all.. look at your network calls.

Comment: PHP code should start with `<?php` yours start with `<?`... this is why everything is echoed out and you don't get HTML back from server.. I will post my working version of your code shortly.

Comment: you are inconsistent. sometimes it is textarea-input and sometimes title_input - go over all of them and make sure they are all aligned. underscore is better.

Comment: in your PHP - you are referring to "title_input" and "textarea-input" but you should refer to "title" and "textarea" - look at your ajax JSON keys..

Comment: one other thing, for your title and your text input you are using the same ID... your gonna have issues here if they are both on the same page: <span id="resultval">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments :

You should first add the echoed html from PHP, only then can you access it from jquery with $("#resultval")

I will explain - look at your "success" handler

```
  success: function(result) {
                    $('#textarea_result').html( $('#resultval', result).html());
                    $('#title_result').html( $('#resultval', result).html());
                    }
```

The code should be

```
  success: function(result) {
                    $('#textarea_result').html( result);
                    $('#title_result').html( result);
                    }
```

If at all.. but I don't think that it what you meant.

If you want to ask me - render the entire next tab in PHP and do something like `$("#tab2").html(result);`

Comment #2 
You have 2 identical IDs - resultval..

Comment #3 - 
You are sending "textarea" and "title" in Ajax, but referring to $_POST["textarea_input"] and $_POST["title-input"]

Comment #4 - 
You are using `$("#textarea-input").html()` to get the value instead of `$("#textarea-input").val()`. same for "title_input"

Here is my working version ( just remove the "head" stuff ).

This is my main.php -

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stackoverflow/public/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="/stackoverflow/public/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/stackoverflow/public/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
        <div id="tabs">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tab-1"> TAB1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-2"> TAB2</a></li>

           </ul>

<div id="tab-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
        <label for="title_input">Title</label>
     <input type="text" id="title_input" name="title_input" size="60" autocomplete="off" value="my title"/><br>
     <label for="textarea-input">Textarea</label>
     <textarea id="textarea-input" name="textarea-input"></textarea> 
</div>

<div id="tab-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide"> 

</div>          



        </div>




 </div>



<script>  
var currentTab = 0;
        $(function() {
            var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
                disabled: [0, 1]
                , select: function() {
                    console.log("selecting a new tab " + currentTab);
                    if (currentTab == 0) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "tabs.php",
                            data: { "textarea": $("#textarea-input").val(),
                    "title": $("#title_input").val()
                   },
                success: function(result) {
                        $("#tab-2").html(result);

                    }       
                        });

        }
                }
                , show: function(event, ui) {
                    currentTab = ui.index;
                }
            });

$(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(i) {
  var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;
       if (i != totalSize) {
              next = i + 2;
               $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Next Page &#187;</a>");
                }
        if (i != 0) {
              prev = i;
              $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'>&#171; Prev Page</a>");
              }
});

$('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() {
    var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
    $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex)
    .tabs('select', tabIndex)
    .tabs("option","disabled", [0, 1]);
    return false;
            });
});
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

And this is my "tabs.php"

My working example can be found at [my site](http://www.mograbi.info/stackoverflow/main.html)

```
<?php
    echo "This is the result are you ready?";
if (isset($_POST['title'])){
    $title = $_POST['title']; 
    echo ('<div id="title_result"><span id="resultval"><h2>Title Echo result:</h2>'.$title.'</span></div>');
            }
            else{
                echo "title_input is not defined!";
            }

if (isset($_POST['textarea'])){
    $textarea = $_POST['textarea']; 
    echo ('<div id="textarea_result"><span id="resultval"><h2>Textarea Echo result:</h2>'.$textarea.'</span></div>');
                       }
?>
```

Let me know if there's anything else.

Comment: +1 Thankyou I have edited the code accordingly to your answer and Jeffrey A Wooden. But now I am getting the incorrect php echo.

Comment: Yes I know - you have some more syntax errors. please have a look at my comments I am posting as I am working on a working version of your code.

Comment: thank you for being patient and walking me through my syntax error riddled code. I follow every step and seems to work but with exception that is echoing something extra. Please check it out.

Comment: what is the extra "thing" that is echo'd?

Comment: This is mine for debugging. you can remove it.

Comment: @JefferyAWooden I am geting echoed on top of my result this: `TAB1` and `TAB2`.

Comment: +1 @JefferyAWooden thanks for the advice. I was using firebug tool but will start now using more chrome tools.

Comment: Is the data being properly posted when u inspect ising network tools? If so.we can narrow it down to the PHP response

Comment: @JefferyAwooden, I have copied the exact same php for posting, ajax/js function, the values from this answer. But The results are different. The chrom network tools show in the form data the following: `textarea:asdf` & `title:sfasdf` which is what i typed in. But it looks like extra html attributes are being echoed besides the desired values.

Comment: @guymograbi I have copied everything Identical but getting a different result echo out.

Comment: @charliecodex23 - I will create zip of my files at my site so you can download and play with it.

Comment: @charliecodex23 - ok I've placed a link to download all resources. Simply extract it somewhere and go to "ROOT/stackoverflow/main.html" use http://www.mograbi.info/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.zip to download

Comment: @charliecodex23, like jeffery said, I posted a page to explain how to use the developer tools http://wiki.mograbi.info/developers-tools-for-web-development. hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into cleaning up your HTML first and utilizing PHP correctly... your HTML tab 2 should be:

```
<div id="tab-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
     <input type="text" id="title_input" name="title_input" size="60" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$title?>"/><br>
     <label for="textarea-input">Textarea</label>
     <textarea id="textarea-input" name="textarea-input"><?=$textarea?></textarea> 
</div>

<div id="tab-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide"> 
    <div id="title_result" style="padding:20px;"></div>
    <div id="textarea_result" style="padding:20px;"></div>
</div>
```

You had an extra quote after title_input name and also when you want to spit out PHP code without an echo, use it like this:

```
<?=$title?>
```

also by the way, you have additional dirty code in your php... this:

```
if (isset($_POST['title_input"'])){
    $title = $_POST['title_input"']; 
    echo ('<div id="title_result"><span id="resultval"><h2>Title Echo result:</h2>'.$title.'</span></div>');
}
```

should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['title_input'])){
    $title = $_POST['title_input"']; 
    echo ('<div id="title_result"><span id="resultval"><h2>Title Echo result:</h2>'.$title.'</span></div>');
}
```

you had an additional quote in the php here:

```
$_POST['title_input"']
```

go through and clean up your code

Comment: +1 THank you, I have done so accordingly to your answer. Now I am running into a different problem.

Comment: Ill be glad to help... but what is the new issue after modifying your code? Edit your question and post the latest issues after your original comment